# How to perform client-side form-validation on password

Tags: javascript, html, client-side

I am doing a simple sign-up page. For the password stuff, I need to check the new password and confirmed password are the same but no idea how

```
                            <div class="row">
                                <!--New Username-->
                                <div class="large-4 columns form-text">New Username</div>
                                <div class="large-8 columns">
                                    <div class="input-icon font-awesome">&#xf007;</div><input type="text" class="form-input" name="username" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br/>
                            <div class="row">
                                <!--New email-->
                                <div class="large-4 columns form-text">Email</div>
                                <div class="large-8 columns">
                                    <div class="input-icon font-awesome">&#xf003;</div><input type="email" class="form-input" name="email" pattern="[a-zA-Z]*@[a-zA-Z]*" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br/>
                            <div class="row">
                                <!--New Passwrord-->
                                <div class="large-4 columns form-text">New Password</div>
                                <div class="large-8 columns">
                                    <div class="input-icon font-awesome">&#xf084;</div><input type="password" class="form-input" name="password" required> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br/>
                            <div class="row">
                                <!--Reconfirm new password-->
                                <div class="large-4 columns form-text">Re-enter Password</div>
                                <div class="large-8 columns">
                                    <div class="input-icon font-awesome">&#xf084;</div><input type="password" class="form-input" name="password-confirm" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: How far have you gotten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's quite a bit of code, but I broke out an example on a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/4zw5V/).

Simplified HTML:

```
<form id="passwordForm" action="#" method="POST">
    Password:<br>
    <input type="password" id="password"><br>
    Confirm Password:<br>
    <input type="password" id="confirmPassword"><br>
    <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Check 'Em">
</form>
<div id="responseDiv"></div>
```

I used jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submitButton").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var matched,
            password = $("#password").val(),
            confirm = $("#confirmPassword").val();

        matched = (password == confirm) ? true : false;
        if(matched) { 
            //Submit line commented out for example.  In production, remove the //
            //$("#passwordForm").submit(); 

            //Shows success message and prevents submission.  In production, comment out the next 2 lines.
            $("#responseDiv").html("Passwords Match");
            return false;
    }
    else { 
        $("#responseDiv").html("Passwords don't match..."); 
        return false;
    }
});
```

});

Many times new learners will forget the e.preventDefault();  Without it, the form will submit regardless of any validation.  Return false if there is something wrong, and the form will not submit.

There is an event listener on the submit button.  If it is clicked, or the enter key is pressed will focused in the form, it will run the validation.  If everything is fine, it will post the information to the URL in the action attribute of the form tag.

Another important point is to always re-validate on the server side.  If a user has their Javascript turned off the form will post the information regardless of what is in your validation script.

Comment: how do u automatically direct the user to some other page if the match check is passed?

Comment: do u need to click to check this two values are match or not?

Comment: Previously my code demonstrated how to check if the text within each box matched.  I have updated it to demonstrate the actual submission after the check.  If you have any other questions, don't hesitate to ask!

Answer (score 0):

with normal javascript, just adapt to your source code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

<script>
function pass() {
    var pass_1 = document.forms["myForm"].pass_1.value.length;
    var pass_2 = document.forms["myForm"].pass_2.value.length;
    if (pass_1 != pass_2) {
        alert("the pass and repeat pass must be equal");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="" name="myForm" onSubmit="pass(); return false;">
    <input type="password" placeholder="type your pass" name="pass_1">
    <input type="password" placeholder="confirm your pass" name="pass_2">
<input type="submit" value="validate">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

the same code above but with the redirect: http://jsfiddle.net/m7BrM/

option 2 use a plugin:
http://www.technicalkeeda.com/jquery/password-and-confirm-password-validation-in-jquery